# Do I have to play a Dead of Winter event card as soon as I draw it, or can I choose to play it later?

Tags: dead-of-winter

When you draw an event card which says to add new people to your colony, does that go into effect right away or can you decide when to play it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You decide when (or if) to play any card from the item deck, including Event cards that add survivors. Players may play item cards (including event cards) on their turn, but they are not required to do so.

The one difference with Event cards is that they are not added to the waste pile but are instead removed from game.

Unfortunately the rulebook doesn't do a good job explaining Event cards, but this topic has come up repeatedly on the BGG rules forum. One such link posted below where one of the co-designers Jonathan Gilmour comments on a thread specific to this rule.

http://boardgamegeek.com/article/17160807#17160807

Comment: Do you have a reference for Event cards being removed from game instead of going to the Waste Pile? The rulebook just says "To play a card, place it on top of the waste pile", with only an exception for Equipment.

Comment: Nevermind. Apparently this sentence made it into the printed rulebook but somehow not the PDF!

Comment: It seems ridiculous that the online PDF isn't the most up to date version, but it appears to be so. I myself was searching it for mention of Event cards and trash and found the printed version to contain this reference where the online version didn't.  Odd.